Querydsl - How can I query one to many relationship using Projections
I have an order entity that has a stops property which is onetomany.
Order entity
@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE orders SET deleted_at = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE id = ?")
@Where(clause = "deleted_at is null")
class Order(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    var id: Long? = null
    var totalAmount: Double? = null,
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "order", cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
    @JsonManagedReference
    var stops: MutableSet<Stop> = mutableSetOf()
}

ViewOrder Dto
data class ViewOrderDtoV2(
    var id: Long? = null,
    var totalAmount: Double? = null,
    var stops: MutableSet<StopDto> = mutableSetOf()
){
data class StopDto(
        var id: Long? = null,
        var name: String? = null
)
}

I am trying to use querydsl to query the id and totalAmount on orders and id and name on stops.
But i get an error.
Here is my querydsl query, PS: I am using kotlin
queryFactory
                .select(
                    Projections.bean(
                        ViewOrderDtoV2::class.java,
                        QOrder.order.id,
                        QOrder.order.totalAmount,
                        Projections.list(
                            Projections.bean(
                                ViewOrderDtoV2.StopDto::class.java,
                                QStop.stop.id,
                                QStop.stop.name
                            ).`as`(ViewOrderDtoV2::stops.name)
                        )
                    )
                )
                .from(QOrder.order)
                .where(expression)
                .orderBy(QOrder.order.startDateTime.desc())
                .distinct()

The error I get is
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported expression new List(new StopDto(stop.id, stop.name) as stops)...

